# How to remove a particular class from the list of classnames defined

Tags: blazor

Need to remove a particular class from a list of class names provided. I have found only the **Remove()** methods which removes the entire key value from the element. I don't need that.

Code block

`<div class="test1 test2 test3">`

I need to remove the class `test2` from the above class names.

can any one suggest a solution for this ?

Comment: You did not mention what language or framework you want to use.

Comment: Added the label as blazor

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example the toggle button adds or removes the disabled class

the select binds to  the cssType

the 'btn-lg' is there to show you that you do not need to make all classes variables

```
<div class="@ccsButton @ccsType @ccsDisabled btn-lg"> Testing</div>

<div style="margin-top:10px;">
    <button @onclick="ToggleEnable"  >Toggle Enable</button>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:10px;">
    <select @bind="ccsType">
        <option value="btn-primary" >btn-primary</option>
        <option value="btn-warning" >btn-warning</option>
        <option value="btn-success" >btn-success</option>
    </select>
</div>

@code{

 string ccsButton = "btn";
 string ccsType = "btn-primary";
 string ccsDisabled = "disabled";

void ToggleEnable()
{
    if(ccsDisabled == ""){ccsDisabled ="disabled";} else {ccsDisabled ="";}
}

}
```

Here is a [Link](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/khk3zt8h) to this example in BlazorFiddle